# Unable to deploy Worklight adapter in remote server

Tags: ssl, deployment, certificate, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm experiencing an issue while deploying worklight adapter in a remote machine.
Adapter is using a certificate alias.

Here is the message of error:

```
Invalid content was found starting with element 'sslCertificateAlias'. 
One of '{authentication, proxy}' is expected.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you attach here your adapter xml without sensitive data?
Anyway check if your remote server keystore contains private key with alias you are configured in sslCertificateAlias and the password in sslCertificatePassword is right.
A second check is configuration of the keystore in worklight.properties:

```
ssl.keystore.path=conf/default.keystore
ssl.keystore.type=jks
ssl.keystore.password=mypassword
```

Comment: <connectivity>
 <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
   <protocol>https</protocol>
   <domain>123.sso.xxx.com</domain>
   <port>443</port>     <sslCertificateAlias>app_cert</sslCertificateAlias> 
   <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>    
  </connectionPolicy>
  <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" /></connectivity>
 <procedure name="getStories"/>
 <procedure name="getStoriesFiltered"/>
 <procedure name="getInitData"/>
 <procedure name="checkSSOSession"/>
 <procedure name="logintoSSO"/>

Comment: Please note that I'm deploying this adapter developed in Worklight Studio 6.1 in a Worklight server 5.0. Will that make any difference

Comment: There is no SSL in 5.0, you need new server for this feature.